# Wso2 Esb sequence template calling endpoint template

Tags: templates, wso2, esb, endpoint, wso2-esb

I am trying to implement a sequence template that calls a endpoint template leveraging the parameters. 
My code is as follows:

SEQUENCE-

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="aFileWriteSequence" trace="disable">
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="sequence" value="aFileWriteSequence"></property>
   </log>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="filename" expression="get-property('transport', 'FILE_NAME')" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
   <call-template target="FileWriteTemplate">
      <with-param name="targetFileName" value="A_TITLE"></with-param>
      <with-param name="addressUri" value="vfs:file:///var/process/ren/rrout"></with-param>
   </call-template>
</sequence>
```

SEQUENCE TEMPLATE-

```
<template xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="FileWriteTemplate">
   <parameter name="targetFileName"></parameter>
   <parameter name="addressUri"></parameter>
   <sequence>
      <log level="custom">
         <property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="TARGET_FILE_NAME" expression="$func:targetFileName"></property>
         <property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ADDRESS_URI" expression="$func:addressUri"></property>
      </log>
      <property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" expression="fn:concat($func:targetFileName, '-', get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyMMddHHmmss') , '.xml')" scope="transport" type="STRING"></property>
      <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"></property>
      <send>
         <endpoint name="ep" template="FileOutEndpointTemplate" uri="$func:addressUri">
            <axis2ns117:parameter xmlns:axis2ns117="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="retries" value="3"></axis2ns117:parameter>
            <axis2ns118:parameter xmlns:axis2ns118="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="codes" value="1001"></axis2ns118:parameter>
            <axis2ns119:parameter xmlns:axis2ns119="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="factor" value="1.0"></axis2ns119:parameter>
         </endpoint>
      </send>
   </sequence>
</template>
```

ENDPOINT TEMPLATE-

```
<template xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="FileOutEndpointTemplate">
   <axis2ns131:parameter xmlns:axis2ns131="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="codes"></axis2ns131:parameter>
   <axis2ns132:parameter xmlns:axis2ns132="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="factor"></axis2ns132:parameter>
   <axis2ns133:parameter xmlns:axis2ns133="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="retries"></axis2ns133:parameter>
   <endpoint name="$name">
      <address uri="$uri">
         <suspendOnFailure>
            <errorCodes>$codes</errorCodes>
            <progressionFactor>$factor</progressionFactor>
         </suspendOnFailure>
         <markForSuspension>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>$retries</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
         </markForSuspension>
      </address>
   </endpoint>
</template>
```

I have tried several variations on the $Uri in particular and I cannot get it to work.  Essentially, here is the error I am getting:

```
2015-09-17 16:23:31,026 [-] [SynapseWorker-19] ERROR ClientUtils The system cannot infer the transport information from the $func:addressUri URL.
2015-09-17 16:23:31,026 [-] [SynapseWorker-19] ERROR Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the $func:addressUri URL.
```

I would appreciate any recommendation anyone would have to configure this line:

```
<endpoint name="ep" template="FileOutEndpointTemplate" uri="$func:addressUri">
```

Especially how to code the parameter **addressUri** being passed in from the sequence template call in my sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Address endpoint doesn't support dynamic endpoints. So you can't pass a dynamic value (`$func:addressUri` is dynamic) to `uri` parameter of template endpoint. Hence if you want to have a dynamic endpoint, then you can use a default endpoint together with a "To" header which you can set dynamically. Here is the changes to your artifacts.

1. No changes to your sequence
2. Set `To` header using header mediator in your sequence template just before the send mediator, as shown below.

```xml
<template xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="FileWriteTemplate">
   <parameter name="targetFileName"></parameter>
   <parameter name="addressUri"></parameter>
   <sequence>
      <log level="custom">
         <property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="TARGET_FILE_NAME" expression="$func:targetFileName"></property>
         <property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ADDRESS_URI" expression="$func:addressUri"></property>
      </log>
      <property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" expression="fn:concat($func:targetFileName, '-', get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyMMddHHmmss') , '.xml')" scope="transport" type="STRING"></property>
      <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"></property>
      <header name="To"  expression="$func:addressUri"/> 
      <send>
         <endpoint name="ep" template="FileOutEndpointTemplate">
            <axis2ns117:parameter xmlns:axis2ns117="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="retries" value="3"></axis2ns117:parameter>
            <axis2ns118:parameter xmlns:axis2ns118="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="codes" value="1001"></axis2ns118:parameter>
            <axis2ns119:parameter xmlns:axis2ns119="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="factor" value="1.0"></axis2ns119:parameter>
         </endpoint>
      </send>
   </sequence>
</template>
```

3. Change address endpoint to default endpoint in your endpoint template, as shown below

```xml
<template xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="FileOutEndpointTemplate">
   <axis2ns131:parameter xmlns:axis2ns131="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="codes"></axis2ns131:parameter>
   <axis2ns132:parameter xmlns:axis2ns132="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="factor"></axis2ns132:parameter>
   <axis2ns133:parameter xmlns:axis2ns133="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="retries"></axis2ns133:parameter>
   <endpoint name="$name">
      <default>
         <suspendOnFailure>
            <errorCodes>$codes</errorCodes>
            <progressionFactor>$factor</progressionFactor>
         </suspendOnFailure>
         <markForSuspension>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>$retries</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
         </markForSuspension>
      </default>
   </endpoint>
</template>
```

The idea behind this solution is that you can set `To` header dynamically and the default endpoint will send the messages out to the endpoint found in "To" header.

Refer [this](http://blog.rajkumarr.com/2015/06/wso2-esb-dynamic-jms-endpoint.html)  for more details.

[1](http://blog.rajkumarr.com/2015/06/wso2-esb-dynamic-jms-endpoint.html)

Comment: Thank you for the information and the recommendation Rajkumar! I have implemented your recommendations and it works great. Thanks again!